# JSSOR Slider Min-Height change needed

Tags: slider, jssor

> "jssor slider will always keep aspect ratio while scale. so min-height is not reasonable"

hi all, i need a min-height function for the image in order to keep my page layout consistent.

Does anyone know how to modify the js code?

A flexible dynamic width is good but at some point i need a min-height to anchor the image to a consistent page layout.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth) {
        //for example minHeight is 300;
        var minHeight = 300;

        var newWidth = parentWidth;
        var newHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight() / jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth() * newWidth;

        if (newHeight < minHeight)
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight(minHeight);
        else
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Comment: does that still allow for flexible width??

It looks new so i will give it a shot

Comment: `//var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
          var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();`



i am trying to align it center in the parent box, but it s not any more?

Also, dont you need to scale the width regardless of the height?

Comment: to align it center to parent container, please use css `margin: 0 auto;` for example `<div id="slider1_container" style="margin: 0 auto; position relative; ...`